# Combining dependencies with data providers

Tags: php, phpunit

I have one test method that depends on another method that itself uses a data provider in PHPUnit:

```
/** 
 * @dataProvider getFields
 */
public function testCanDoSomeStuff($parm1, $parm2) {
  $result = my_func($parm1, $parm2);
  $this->assertNotNull($result);

  return $result;
}

/**
 * @depends testCanDoSomeStuff
 */
public function testCanDoSomeMoreStuff($result) {
  $this->assertNotNull($result);
}
```

I also have a `getFields()` data provider function, no need to show that here.

The first test that relies on the data provider passes - `$result` is NOT null.

I expect that the result of the test will be passed to the dependent test as the `$result` parameter. However, the `testCanDoSomeMoreStuff` function receives a `NULL` parameter and the test fails.

**Update**

This simple test case demonstrates the problem:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @dataProvider myFunc
     */
    public function testCanDoSomeStuff($value) {
        $this->assertNotNull($value);
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testCanDoSomeStuff
     */
    public function testCanDoSomeMoreStuff($value) {
        $this->assertNotNull($value);
    }

    /**
     * Data provider function
     */
    public function myFunc() {
      $values = array('22');
      return array($values);
    }
}
```

As a workaround for now, I've stored the result in a static property between tests.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($results);` to see what's being passed to `testCanDoSomeMoreStuff()` ?

Comment: Hi Uzyn, yes - null is being passed.  I also printed the result of the call to 'my_func', which is not null.

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. Perhaps you may want to share your actual code, there might be some errors in the actual one.

Comment: Thanks Uzyn; unfortunately, I am not allowed to post the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the result of several factors:

- Each test result is stored in an array using the test's name as the key.
- The name for a test that receives data is `<name> with data set #<x>`.
- The `@depends` annotation doesn't accept multiple words.

There is a hacky workaround: override `TestCase::getDataSetAsString` to return a name that the annotation will accept. This is made slightly problematic since the required `TestCase` fields are private, but with PHP 5.3.2+ you can get around that.

> **Important:** Unfortunately, you cannot have the dependent test run for *every* data row--only one specific row. If your data provider returns only one row of data, this isn't an issue.

Here's the code with a sample test. Note that you don't have to name your data row. If you leave off the `'foo'` key, change the `@depends` to `testOne-0`.

```
class DependencyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider data
     */
    public function testOne($x, $y) {
        return $x + $y;
    }

    public function data() {
        return array(
            'foo' => array(1, 2),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne-foo
     */
    public function testTwo($z) {
        self::assertEquals(3, $z);
    }

    protected function getDataSetAsString($includeData = false) {
        if (!$includeData && $this->getPrivateField('data')) {
            return '-' . $this->getPrivateField('dataName');
        }
        return parent::getDataSetAsString($includeData);
    }

    private function getPrivateField($name) {
        $reflector = new ReflectionProperty('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', $name);
        $reflector->setAccessible(true);
        return $reflector->getValue($this);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is not a long-term solution. It would be better of you could have the dependent test run once for each test result from the method receiving the data. You could submit a feature request or pull request to PHPUnit.

Comment: Thanks David, that's very useful.  I reported the issue on github yesterday along with the example code, so I guess I'll leave it with them for now.

Answer (score 2):

If your `$result` in `testCanDoSomeStuff()` is really not `null`, then this *should* work.

To take this apart, first try to simplify it without the data provider, something like this:

```
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testCanDoSomeStuff() {
        $result = true;
        $this->assertTrue($result); 
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testCanDoSomeStuff
     */
    public function testCanDoSomeMoreStuff($result) {
        $this->assertNotNull($result);
    }
}
```

Testing this should result into something like...

```
~>phpunit test.php
PHPUnit 3.6.11 by Sebastian Bergmann.
..
Time: 1 second, Memory: 3.25Mb
OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

Now add the data provider, replace my simple variable with your function and then test it again.

If this result differs, `var_dump` the variable `$result` before you return it in testcase `testCanDoSomeStuff()`. If it isn't `null` there, [bug the behaviour](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).

Comment: Hi Bjoern.  Sorry, I should have added that this was exactly what I also tried, and it worked.  Thanks for the link, I'll try to recreate the issue in a class that I can submit as part of the bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I also expected the problem described to work, and after some research, I found out that this is not a bug, but an expected, not documented, behavior. The dependent test does not know about the data sets returned by the provider, and that's why the test parameter is null.

Source: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/183#issuecomment-816066

> The @dataProvider annotations get computed before test execution. Basically, the pre-test phase creates a test method for every set of parameters provided by the data provider. The @depends is dependent upon what is essentially the prototype of the data driven test, so in a way the @depends is on a non-existent (not executed test).
>
> Another way to think of it, is that if provider was supplying more than one set of parameters. PHPUnit would make that many testDataProvider methods but there would not be that many testDataReceiver methods because there is not an @dataProvider method on that test method for the pre-test phase.
>
> You can however had @depends and @dataProvider on the same test method. Just be careful to get the parameter order right, although in this case there may not be a first parameter.

Basically, you should use data providers when the data set has multiple rows. However, you can always use `@depend` and `@dataProvider` at the same time to achieve roughly the same behavior.